# Why set -m is not working? Giving me error job control is turned off!

Tags: bash, docker, job-control, docker-compose

I am trying to execute an entryscript for docker container. I have build this image from php-fpm alpine linux (7.3 version). Once the container is started it should execute some commands in prior, I know docker containers are meant for single process. But I can't spin up another container for the execution of a single command. So I am running a entryscript to do this, in which I have to suspend the main process temporarily to execute few commands then resume the main process which php-fpm. So normally am using set -m command in the script and suspending the php-fpm to run in the background. After executing the commands php-fpm will be brought back to foreground using the command fg %1. Below is my entrypoint script  **my_wrapper_script.sh**.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -m
php-fpm &
php artisan swagger-lume:generate
fg %1
```

**Below is my Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.3-fpm-alpine
WORKDIR /var/www

RUN apk update && apk add \
    postgresql-dev \
    build-base \
    freetype-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libzip-dev \
    zip \
    jpegoptim optipng pngquant gifsicle \
    vim \
    unzip \
    git \
    curl

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_pgsql pdo_mysql mbstring zip exif pcntl
RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ --with-png-dir=/usr/include/
RUN docker-php-ext-install gd

RUN addgroup -g 1000 -S www && \
adduser -u 1000 -S www -G www

USER www

 
ADD ./my_wrapper_script.sh /usr/sbin/my_wrapper_script.sh
COPY --chown=www:www . /var/www
EXPOSE 9000    
ENTRYPOINT ["sh","/usr/sbin/my_wrapper_script.sh"]
```

Comment: You're running the script with `sh`, not `bash`. Not sure what `sh` in Alpine is, but that might be a problem.

Comment: Thanks bro! it was the  problem, only I need to install bash as Alpine versions doesn't come with bash